# C++ shared ptr release on multiple references

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I have an hierarchy where `A` is an abstract class and `B`, `C`, and `D` are descendants of `A`. I have a class `Controller` (MVC pattern) with a shared pointer to `A`:

```
class Controller {

private: 
 int it;
 std::shared_ptr<A> theBase;

public:
 void doCall();
//more code

}
```

Inside `doCall()` I do this:

```
void doCall() {

  switch (it) {
    case 4:
      theBase = std::make_shared<B>( B(8) );
      break;
    case 3:
      theBase = std::make_shared<C>( C(6) );
      break;
    default:
      theBase = std::make_shared<D>( D(0) );
      break;
    }

  theBase->method();

}
```

In this way I can properly use smart pointers and I can use inheritance to get the class that I need according to the value of `it`.

Suppose that I call this code:

```
Controller x;
x.doCall();
x.doCall();
```

I am calling `doCall()` twice, so I am going in the `switch` twice. This means that `std::make_shared` is called twice and assigning to `theBase`. Is this safe?

When I call `doCall()` for the first time, I have a shared pointer. The second time I am assigning another `std::shared_ptr` to `theBase`, and I wonder: is the old pointer (the one of the first call) destroyed and a new one is created? Or do I have to do something like this?

```
if (*theBase != nullptr) {
  theBase.reset(); //delete the old one;
}

switch (it) { /* ... */}
```

Each time `doCall()` is called, I have to create a new object that is a subclass of `theBase`. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Have a read:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator%3D  _"If *this already owns an object and it is the last shared_ptr owning it, and r is not the same as *this, the object is destroyed through the owned deleter."_

Comment: @RichardCritten As I suspected there is no need to call reset(), when I assing theBase = std::make_shared for the 2nd time the old pointer is deleted and a new one is created. No memory leaks and we're all happy. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do nothing. When you assign the newly created `shared_ptr` to `theBase`, the old one's reference counter will be decremented. However the old one's counter is 1(if we assume you are not referencing it somewhere else). The counter reaches 0 and the destructor is called.

Take a look at the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>

class myClass
{
public:
    myClass(int i) : m_i(i) { printf("Constructed %d\n", m_i); }
    ~myClass() { printf("Destructed %d\n", m_i); }

    int m_i;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<myClass> ptr = std::make_shared<myClass>(5);

    ptr = std::make_shared<myClass>(10);
}
```

The output is:

```
Constructed 5
Constructed 10
Destructed 5
Destructed 10
```

The first pointer is destructed just after the second one is created(more specifically when assigned; that's where the first one's counter is decremented).